# Can't create an instance of my class

Tags: php, html, function, class

i'm sorry if this is a noob question, but i can't figure it out.

I have a .php file containing a class:

```
<?php
   class Visitors
   {
      public function greetVisitor()
      {
         echo "Hello<br />";
      }

      function sayGoodbye()
      {
         echo "Goodbye<br />";
      }
   }
?>
```

In another php file containing mostly HTML, i try to create an instance of this class and call the function greetVisitor :

```
            <div class="map col-md-4">
                <?php
                    $test = new Visitors();
                    $test->sayGoodbye();
                ?>
            </div>
```

For some reason this isn't displaying when i look in my browser. Any ideas ?
tried doing a var_dump, but nothing is showing
thanks

Comment: Are you including the former file in the second?

Comment: Does where you're calling `new Visitors()` from have access to the class? Did you import it?

Comment: What do you see if you [turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/300836)?

Answer (score 0):

Before you create an object of the class Visitors you need to include/require the php file where that class is defined, like this:
    
By the way, do not use the parenthesis since you are not sending any values 
and yes you are a newbie!